# User.Identity with empty properties when running app on Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication, kestrel

I have two situations during windows authentication using Active Directory domain identities:

1. When I running my app with IIS I'm getting object WindowsPrincipal filled with information
2. When I running my app with Kestrel I'm getting object ClaimsPrincipal without any informatiion about the user information
   [image]

What could be the problem?

My ConfigureService:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddScoped<IUserManagementManager, UserManagementManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IRolesManagementManager, RolesManagementManager>();
           
        }
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseResponseCaching();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Authentication}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure Windows Authentication in the Kestrel? I found that the attribute of IsAuthenticated in your image is **false**. This may cause you can not get any information about the ClaimsPrincipal.

You can use invoke AddAuthentication and AddNegotiate in Startup.ConfigureServices to add authentication services in Kestrel.

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
```

More information about how to config windows Authentication in the Kestrel you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I'm not mentioned it, but I did it

Comment: If so, then why is your IsAuthenticated attribute is false?

Comment: This is my question. Why all properties are null?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, what you should do is whether all properties is empty when IsAuthenticated attribute is true.

Comment: When I running with Kestrel IsAuthenticated also false. Only with IIS IsAuthenticated  is true

Comment: So is all properties null in IIS?

Comment: No' I mentioned in my question that all properties has values

Comment: So the reason is obvious, this is caused by the failure of the authentication.

Comment: Why it is depending on which server I running my app?

Comment: Your authentication failed in Kestrel, before solving this problem, please solve the authentication problem.

Comment: But there is no problem with authentication when I running with IIS!

Comment: iis is different from Kestrel, in Kestrel you need to add the code in my answer to configure Windows Authentication. `services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();`

Comment: Bro, take a look at my question, I already have this configuration...

Comment: What browser are you using? It may also be caused by the browser, you can refer to this link: [https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Nov/14/FireFox-Windows-Security-and-Kestrel-on-ASPNET-Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Nov/14/FireFox-Windows-Security-and-Kestrel-on-ASPNET-Core).